# Requesting READ_PROFILE permission at runtime

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

According to the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Profile.html), I need to request the `android.permission.READ_PROFILE` permission to read the user's profile information.

However, when I attempt to create runtime permission request, there is no `Manifest.permission.READ_PROFILE` I can use.  Do I just use the `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` permission instead?

**Note:** The AndroidManifest.xml file can find the permission just fine:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

READ_PROFILE permission was removed on API 23 as you can see here

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html

You should ask for GET_ACCOUNTS, or any of the permissions belonging to the CONTACTS group

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#perm-groups